# asyncio.create_task uvicorn.serve() always single worker

Tags: python, python-asyncio, uvicorn

I have such code

```
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from core.deps import app as app_fastapi
from app.scheduler import app as app_rocketry


class Server(uvicorn.Server):
    def handle_exit(self, sig: int, frame) -> None:
        app_rocketry.session.shut_down()
        return super().handle_exit(sig, frame)


async def main():
    server = Server(config=uvicorn.Config(app_fastapi, workers=4, loop='asyncio'))

    application = asyncio.create_task(server.serve())
    scheduler = asyncio.create_task(app_rocketry.serve())

    await asyncio.wait([scheduler, application])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem is that regardless of the number of workers, uvicorn. I always have one worker!

Tell me what the problem is and how to solve it :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-programmatically), running the server programmatically does not have support for multiple workers;

> Note that the application instance itself can be passed instead of the app import string.
>
> ```py
> uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
> ```
>
> However, this style only works if you are not using multiprocessing (workers=NUM) or reloading (reload=True), so we recommend using the import string style.

You must run your server using the CLI. The recommended way is using `gunicorn` for production and `uvicorn` for development. See docs [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-programmatically).